# CHAP vs MS-CHAPv2

Tags: ipsec

I'm setting up an L2TP/IPSec VPN, and I can't find any information about this. MS-CHAPv2 has a known vulnerability that makes cracking it relatively easy. Is CHAP more secure? Does MS-CHAPv2's vuln make it less secure than CHAP?

I understand how CHAP works. Is MS-CHAPv2 more or less secure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is CHAP authentication still secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127496/is-chap-authentication-still-secure)

Comment: @forest Thanks. After reading that, I now understand how CHAP works. However, I still need to know how MSCHAPv2 works, and whether one is more secure than the other.

Comment: "CHAP vs MS-CHAPv2"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-CHAP and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957983.aspx and https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/End+of+Days+for+MSCHAPv2/13807/

Comment: @schroeder None of those compare CHAP to MS-CHAPv2. They just explain MS-CHAPv2.

Comment: the wiki has a comparison at the very top - and the links explain why neither are secure